# Getting "Device offline" error even though emulator is running

Tags: device, offline

I just installed the android sdk (3.0) on my Mac 10.6.3.  I started the emulator successfully using

./emulator -avd my_android &

However, when I try and run a forward command using adb, I get the following error ...

davea-mbp2:platform-tools davea$ ./adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully
error: device offline

Does anyone know what the error means?  My emulator is up and running (http://screencast.com/t/bD8WYjZ1) when I run the above command, - Dave

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but anyway - just had the same issue.

I eventually fixed it by deleting the device and creating a similar one with another name. Recreating the device with the same name did not do the trick.